# Linq to SQL with GroupBy and Detail - Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have some SQL and am trying to make the equivalent in LINQ.  This is the SQL:

```
SELECT Categories.CategoryDescription, Categories.CategoryType AS Type, 
       Categories.Category, COUNT(CategoryLinks.OrgID) AS CountOfOrgs 
FROM CategoryLinks 
INNER JOIN Categories ON Categories.CategoryID = CategoryLinks.CategoryID 
GROUP BY Categories.Category, Categories.CategoryType, Categories.CategoryDescription 
ORDER BY CategoryDescription ASC
```

Essentially, I want a list of everything from the Categories table and a count of the number of OrgId's in the CategoryLinks table that links to it.

Below is the query I am performing at the moment. There has to be a more efficient way to do this. Am I wrong?

```
var cnts = (from c in db.Categories
  join cl in db.CategoryLinks on c.CategoryID equals cl.CategoryID
  group new { c, cl } by new
  {
    c.CategoryID
  } into g
  select new
  {
    CategoryID = g.Key.CategoryID,
    categoryCount = g.Count()
  });

  var results = (from c in db.Categories
    join cn in cnts on c.CategoryID equals cn.CategoryID
    select new
    {
      c.CategoryID,
      c.CategoryDescription,
      c.CategoryType,
      Category = c.Category1,
      cn.categoryCount
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the GroupJoin method:

```
Categories.GroupJoin(
    CategoryLinks, 
    x => x.CategoryID, 
    y => y.CategoryID, 
    (x,y) => new{
        x.CategoryID, 
        x.CategoryDescription, 
        x.CategoryType, 
        Category = x.Category1, 
        CategoryCount = y.Count() })
```

In query syntax, this is written as join..into:

```
from c in db.Categories
    join cl in db.CategoryLinks on c.CategoryID equals cl.CategoryID into catGroup
    select new
                   {
                       c.CategoryID,
                       c.CategoryDescription,
                       c.CategoryType,
                       Category = c.Category1,
                       CategoryCount = catGroup.Count()
                   }
```

Comment: For some reason, the count was doubled in my results. I simply divided by 2 and the results seem to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is due to groupjoin that is left outer join not inner join. Try my code in another answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would be getting 2x the count in your results. It is a left outer join, as Kirill says, but that just means that the result includes categories with zero links.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var bbb = categories.Join(categoryLinks, c => c.CategoryID, cl => cl.CategoryId, (c, cl) => new {c, cl})
                    .GroupBy(g => g.c)
                    .Select(g => new {count = g.Count(), Category = g.Key});
```

It returns count and all data that is in Category. We group by all columns in category and place result in new anonymous type variable that contains 2 properties: Count, that contains count and Category that is of type Category and contains all data that is in category row. 
If you want, you can rewrite it as:

```
var bbb = categories.Join(categoryLinks, c => c.CategoryID, cl => cl.CategoryId, (c, cl) => new {c, cl})
                    .GroupBy(g => g.c)
                    .Select(g => new
                                 {
                                    CategoryID = g.Key.CategoryId,
                                    CategoryDescription = g.Key.CategoryDescription,
                                    CategoryType = g.Key.CategoryType,
                                    Category = g.Key.Category1,
                                    categoryCount = g.Count()
                                 });
```

Comment: This solution doesn't return information other than the count of the Category though.

Comment: It returns count and all data that is in Category. We group by all fields in category and place in new anonymous type variable that contains 2 properties: Count, that contains count and Category that is of type Category and contains all data that is in category row.